# J2.5: Default-value of config-item needs to be language-dependend - how to?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am developing an extension for Joomla which should play find with int'l languages. 
Now, in the configuration I have a text-entry - and default-value should vary by language. So I tried this:

```
<field
name="cbm_pfxattblock"
type="text"
label="COM_JOOMLABYMAIL_CONFIG_PFXATTBLOCK"
description="COM_JOOMLABYMAIL_CONFIG_PFXATTBLOCK_DESC"
default="COM_JOOMLABYMAIL_CONFIG_PFXATTBLOCK_DEFAULT"
size=""
filter="raw"
/>
```

But unfortunately this displays the name of the constant and not its value. All other constants were replaced correctly, so I assume it has to do with the default-val which somehow cannot be localized. Is that right? How does one deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used a postflight-function in the installer to replace the default-value in the XML with the actual content of that constant. Worked fine and solved the problem :)